# Simple Approach to Writing/Reading an array of integer and char variables with Android SDK

Tags: java, android, file

I am working on my first game, and I would like to save some game data and read it back at a later point from internal storage.  For example, I have five player names in variables ( PLAYER[1],PLAYER[2],PLAYER[3],PLAYER[4],PLAYER[5] ) and five scores for each player (SCORE[1],SCORE[2],SCORE[3],SCORE[4],SCORE[5]).  How can I use a loop to write the names and scores, and then read them back into their respective variables? I have the Android SDK in Eclipse.

Like in this structure....

for (int i=1; i<6; i++)
 {

write player[i]

write scores[i]

}

and then later...

for (int i=1; i<6; i++)
{

read player names and scores

and put them back into player[i] and score[i]

}

I am rather new to java, but I searched a lot for a simple approach but can't seem to find one.  Any examples for me???

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you could use the built-in database that Android provides.  Check out these links for notes on how to use it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

If that seems like overkill, check out [Shared Prefs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).